# Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment when working with multiple build environment

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I was using scripts to add firebase plist for multiple environments, following [this](https://medium.com/@pablosanchezdev/using-different-firebase-environments-in-an-ios-app-35eb0dd36e7c) tutorial,
Until now everything worked fine, but since I have migrated to Swift 5 & Xcode 12.1, but now it has stopped working

```
'
 if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
    cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/FireBasePlistLive/GoogleService-Info.plist""${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

 echo "Production plist copied"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/FireBasePlistStag/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Development plist copied"
fi
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if this will help anyone

but I would like to tell how I got over this, when nothing on the internet seemed to have worked
I just deleted the file from the project
i.e. **Moved to trash** and then agin added it back
**Clean & Build Again**